# What images evoke the concept of "skin in the game", commitment, investment, and accountability?

Tags: metaphors

What would be a great picture to display (as a visual metaphor) to convey the idea of "skin in the game", commitment, investment, and accountability?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is concerned with the English language, not visual metaphors

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Any suggestions of a site that might be able to help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem all that different from other requests for single-word answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use an image of someone pushing poker chips forward, to signify that they are risking their money.

Answer (score 2):

The image doesn't stand alone without the text, but a plate of ham and eggs is sometimes used to illustrate the difference between *involvement* and *commitment*. The caption: "The chicken is involved... the pig is committed."